# How to delete local scope named range using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, named-ranges

I have an excel workbook with two named ranges.  One is global, one is local to a specific sheet.  I want to delete both.

Using openpyxl, I can delete the global named range using:

`del wb.defined_names['range']`

This works fine.

but when I try the same command to delete the local named range "Date" I get an error:

> File
> "C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\defined_name.py",
> line 231, in **getitem**
> raise KeyError("No definition called {0}".format(name)) KeyError: 'No definition called Date'

How do I delete local named ranges?

Comment: The KeyError is fairly clear, don't you think?

Comment: @CharlieClark the defined range exists with that name. I haven't got the key wrongly named etc, if that's what you're implying.

Comment: If you look at the source, you'll see that `__del__` only works for global names, because scoped ones can be duplicates. You need to use `.delete(name, scope)`

Comment: did you want to put that as answer?  It works.